# how to check data type of a variable in java?

Tags: java, types, typeof

If I convert a String to int. Then how can I confirm the string was converted in int? How can I check those variable data type by if else ?

Comment: Another way of saying this is that you need to read the documentation.  The `Integer.parse()` method specifies how it works.  It explains the error that gets thrown and why, and the return type is the type the method *must* return, there can be no other.  (Methods that return a reference can also return `null`, which is technically a value that could be any type.)

Answer (score -2):

You can use Java's `instanceof` operator to check the data type of an object.

Example:

```
class Simple1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Integer a = 1;
        System.out.println(a instanceof Integer);//true
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't make sense to have some checks but if in case someone wants to check the type of an object when they aren't sure about its type, you can use instanceof operator on if condition to make sure the object is of the expected type.

Comment: But it is irrelevant if you call a method that returns a specific type like `Integer.parseInt()` which is what OP is doing when converting a String to an int. And also remember that `instanceof ` wouldn't work on primitive types like `int`